# Unable to locate Catalog Id/Product Id in my Watson knowledge catalog and project

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-catalog

I created a new catalog in my Watson knowledge Catalog service and added assets to it. Now I want create a new connection to the data source using watson-data-apis from the REST client. It is asking for catalog_id or project_id. Tried looking into my catalog settings and all around, but could not find these ids in my catalog as well as project.
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/watson-data-api#connections

Any help in getting this ids will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the /v2/catalogs API to grab it too but probably the easiest is just to look at it from the UI and grab it in the URL
`data/catalogs/{catalog_id}`